# Get n-th element from stack in Forth

Tags: forth

Is there a way to access an element of the stack by its index in Forth, without popping all the elements above it?

For example, if I have the numbers 1 to 1000 pushed to the stack, how can I get the 500th element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
500 PICK
```

...will copy the element 500 levels down the stack to the top of the stack in Forth79.

More relevant: PICK is in the core extension wordset in ISO93 Forth, the base of the current standard. The definition of PICK in this standard is 0-based, e.g. '0 PICK' is equivalent to 'DUP'. See section 6.2.2030

Comment: So `0 pick` would copy the most recently added element to the stack?

Comment: @sashoalm As far as I can remember, a `2 PICK` is the same as `OVER`, and a `1 PICK` is the same as `DUP`. I don't think `0 PICK` is valid.

Comment: @LarsBrinkhoff That's odd, my memory and when I looked it up [this copy of the standard](https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/lnmaurer/web/forth/Forth-79.pdf) I found (admittedly not checked against the real thing) says on page 27; `2 PICK is quivalent to OVER`.

Comment: @LarsBrinkhoff Admittedly I mostly used Forth around '85, so I'd not trust my memory much ;)

Answer (score 6):

And if the Forth you're using don't have PICK, you could define it as

```
: PICK   ?DUP IF SWAP >R 1- RECURSE R> SWAP EXIT THEN DUP ;
```

(Of course, an iterative version would also be possible.)

Comment: This doesn't qualify because it pops all the elements one by one.